# PHP how to add and array to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of date objects which shows the days of a certain time period. Now I added some holidays, which will add an attribute to that days object which indicates hat it is an holiday. So far so good, but now I want a holiday period, inside the time period of fo example to weeks. So, instead of typing in those days manually, can it be done by adding another array inside the array?

here is my code so far:

```
$holidays = ['2018-09-03','2018-09-25','2018-09-26'];

// Timeperiod
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2018-09-01'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2018-09-30')
);

// The VAcation period I want to add to the time-period-array
$vacationPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2018-09-10'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2018-09-23')
);

$days = [];

foreach($period as $k => $v) {

    $tmpDate = $v->format('Y-m-d');
    $dayNumber = date('w',strtotime($tmpDate));

    if($dayNumber != 0 && $dayNumber != 6) {

        if(in_array($tmpDate,$holidays)) {
            $holiday = true;
        } else {
            $holiday = false;
        }

        $days[] = [
        'date' => $tmpDate,
        'holiday' => $holiday
    ];          
    }       
}

echo json_encode($days);
```

So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: `'holiday_range' => [$tmpDate, $modDate]` sure, I don't see a problem with that. `$modDate = $v->modify('+2 weeks')->format('Y-m-d')`  You can just modify date time with stuff like `+2 weeks` `First day of week` etc.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix your example doesn't work unfortunately. Should it be in the `foreach`-loop?

Comment: Well I don't know I never looped over `$period = new DatePeriod(` so it depends what `$v` is.

Comment: `$v` is the value to go through the array, can't explain it better - Since `in_array` only accepts two values, I don't know how to add addiotional timeperiods

Comment: Obviously, but if it's not a `DateTime` object, then calling a DateTime method on it won't work out to well.